# Adding another EntityType in a formbuilder in Symfony4

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity, formbuilder

is it possible in the Form Builder to add an Entity that is not related to the object where we build the form ?

I try to explain

I've got Article, Category, SuperCategory.
I want my users to first choose the SuperCategory, then the Category, then the Article.

In the form builder I'd like to add the SuperCategory to the ArticleType, but the SuperCategory is a ManyToOne relation in Category which is a ManyToOne relation in Article.

Here's my code:

```
$builder->add('SuperCategory', EntityType::class, [
    'class' => SuperCategory::class,
    'choice_label' => 'Title'
]);
```

As expected, It doesn't work because the Article class doesn't know about SuperCategory.

Still, I need to show these SuperCategory to make a "FormFlow". Is it possible?

Here's the error (as expected, nothing surprising) :

```
"Neither the property "SuperCategory" nor one of the methods 
"getSuperCategory()", "superCategory()", "isSuperCategory()", 
"hasSuperCategory()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class 
"App\Entity\Article".
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$builder->add('SuperCategory', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => SuperCategory::class,
                'choice_label' => 'Title',
                'mapped' => false
]);
```

The

```
'mapped' => false
```

was the solution !